# Anonymous union member access via void pointer

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Let's consider such tagged union:

```
struct TaggedUnion
{
    union
    {
        int integer;
        float real;
        std::string text;
        ...
    };
    size_t disc;
    void* data()
    {
        return &integer;
    }
    //other special member functions for memory management of non-pod union members
};
```

Can I safely do expression(and use it's result) like `*reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(taggedUnionInstance.data())` if I know that `std::string` is active memer of anonymous union?

Comment: For casting to and from void*, static_cast should be preferred

Comment: For an anonymous `union` containing classes, your `struct TaggedUnion` must contain a proper `TaggedUnion() {}` and `~TaggedUnion()` to deal with constructing and destructing the `std::string` object later.

Comment: @Ruks yeah i meant that in "special member functions" comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `TaggedUnion` is a [*StandardLayoutType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType). One property of standard layout types is that one can `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to the object to a pointer to its first non-static data member (standard quote below). Since an anonymous union is just an unnamed object that is also a data member of `TaggedUnion`, according to (9.5/5)

> A union of the form ... is called an *anonymous union*; it defines and unnamed object of unnamed type

this is the first non-static data member. Now, a requirement of standard layout types is that all data members of them are also standard layout, meaning that this union is standard layout. Now, according to the standard (9.2/19, 20, or 21 depending on the version):

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member.

Also: (9.5/1)

> All non-static data members of a union object have the same address

Then the first non-static data member has the same address as all the others, including that of `std::string text`.

Alternatively, if on interprets (9.5/5) differently, by saying that the members of the anonymous union are members of the parent class (which I am not sure about), this still works, since the standard still requires the addresses of the members of an anonymous union to have the same address, so `std::string text` would still have the same address as the first element, `int integer`.

Comment: The fact that pointers hold the same address does not imply that they can actually be used to access the same storage.  The authors of the C Standard didn't think it necessary to mandate that compilers meaningfully process constructs which implementations would unanimously support, though not necessarily for the same reasons, but "modern" compilers have interpreted the lack of a mandate as an invitation to behave nonsensically.

Comment: but a premise of the question was that `std::string text` was the active member of the anonymous union, in which case a pointer pointing to it can be used to access it

Comment: The notion of "active member" is unfortunately rather vague in circumstances where code takes the address of a union member.  For example, given `union U {int a[10]; float b[10];} u;`, would `u.a[5]=1;` set the active member of `u` to `a`?  What about `int *p = u.a; p[5]=1;`?

Comment: the notion of the "active member" of a union is actually defined in the standard: (9.5/1) "In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time". What this implies in the case of your example is that at most one of `a` or `b` can be active at one time; that is, if you assign something to `u.a[5]`, `u.b` is invalidated entirely.

Comment: Perhaps I should have offered up a better example: `struct s1 { int x[10]; }; struct s2 {int x[10];}; union U { s1 v1; s2 v2];} u;` What would `u.v1.x[3] = 4;` do to the "active member"?  How about `int *p = u.v1.x; p[3] = 4;`?

Comment: Actually, in that case, a special rule applies: (9.2/18) "If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence, and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them". The active member would still be whichever was set, but both can be accessed since they share a common initial sequence and are standard-layout.

Comment: Both clang and gcc apply the "common initial sequence" rule only to accesses that are performed directly upon union lvalues, any make no attempt to reliably apply it to actions which are performed by dereferencing pointers to those lvalues, no matter how visibly freshly derived the pointers in question may be at the time of access.  Further, I don't think the Standard is clear about whether one can take the address of a member of a struct which is not an active union member.